# Query conversion from raw to eloquent

Tags: mysql, laravel-4, eloquent

I have this raw query that I want to be convert to eloquent query
I am new to laravel eloquent so I can't translate this somehow complicated query.
can someone translate this for me.

```
     select * from tbl_assets 
left join tbl_asset_validations on (tbl_assets.id = tbl_asset_validations.asset_id  
and (tbl_asset_validations.assetType is null or tbl_asset_validations.assetType = '' or tbl_asset_validations.assetType = 'IT') 
and (tbl_asset_validations.year is null or tbl_asset_validations.year = '' or tbl_asset_validations.year = '2015')  ) 
where (tbl_asset_validations.validation is null or tbl_asset_validations.validation = '' or tbl_asset_validations.validation = 'Not yet validated')
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried yourself? Don't expect others to do all the work if your  question does not show any minimal effort on your side.

Comment: yah, but i have a problem when trying to put the "and" to the left join clause

Comment: $assets = DB::table('tbl_assets')
         ->leftJoin('tbl_asset_validations', function($join)
         {
             $join->on('tbl_assets.id', '=', 'tbl_asset_validations.asset_id')
                  ->whereIn('tbl_asset_validations.assetType', array(null, '', 'IT'))
                  ->whereIn('tbl_asset_validations.year', array(null, '', '2015'))
         })
         ->whereIn('tbl_asset_validations.validation', array(null, '', 'Not yet validated'))
         ->get();